# Base64 encoding/decoding in Nuxt.js with TypeScript and SSR

Tags: nuxt.js

Is there an easy way to encode/decode a string to/from Base64 in Nuxt.js with support for server-side rendering and preferably TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Nuxt 2

There is no way built-in and I didn't find any plugin, so I created a tiny plugin myself, that can simply be dropped into the `/plugins` directory.

```js
import { Plugin } from '@nuxt/types'

function encodeBase64 (value: string): string {
  if (process.client) {
    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(value)))
  } else {
    return Buffer.from(value, 'ascii').toString('base64')
  }
}

function decodeBase64 (value: string): string {
  if (process.client) {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(value)))
  } else {
    return Buffer.from(value, 'base64').toString('ascii')
  }
}

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $encodeBase64: (value: string) => string,
    $decodeBase64: (value: string) => string
  }
}

declare module '@nuxt/types' {
  // nuxtContext.app.$lines inside asyncData, fetch, plugins, middleware, nuxtServerInit
  interface NuxtAppOptions {
    $encodeBase64: (value: string) => string,
    $decodeBase64: (value: string) => string
  }
  // nuxtContext.$lines
  interface Context {
    $encodeBase64: (value: string) => string,
    $decodeBase64: (value: string) => string
  }
}

declare module 'vuex/types/index' {
  // this.$lines inside Vuex stores
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  interface Store<S> {
    $encodeBase64: (value: string) => string,
    $decodeBase64: (value: string) => string
  }
}

const base64Plugin: Plugin = (_context, inject) => {
  inject('encodeBase64', encodeBase64)
  inject('decodeBase64', decodeBase64)
}

export default base64Plugin
```

Don't forget to load it in your `nuxt.config.ts`:

```js
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/base64.ts' },
  ],
```

Now use `$encodeBase64()` and `$decodeBase64()` in your Vue.js components both client-side and server-side.

Answer (score 1):

#### Support for Nuxt 3

**Create a Plugin**
Create a file `base64.ts` in `~/plugins`

```js
function encodeBase64(value: string): string {
    if (process.client) {
        return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(value)))
    } else {
        return Buffer.from(value, 'ascii').toString('base64')
    }
}

function decodeBase64(value: string): string {
    if (process.client) {
        return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(value)))
    } else {
        return Buffer.from(value, 'base64').toString('ascii')
    }
}

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    return {
        provide: {
            encodeBase64,
            decodeBase64
        }
    }
})
```

**Register the plugin**
The plugin should be automagically loaded but if it is not, register the plugin in your `nuxt.config.ts` file

```js
    plugins: [
        { src: '~/plugins/base64.ts' },
    ],
```

**Usage**

```js
    const { $encodeBase64 } = useNuxtApp()
    const encodedString = $encodeBase64(inputString)
```